# Get only one item from a subgroup values

Tags: sql, select

I have this values in my SQL table:

```
A Column | B Column | C Column 
------------------------------
11       | Text1    | 10
11       | Text2    | 20
11       | Text3    | 30
12       | Text4    | 20
12       | Text5    | 15
12       | Text9    | 12
13       | Text60   | 01
13       | Text99   | 05
13       | Text33   | 09
13       | Text0    | 04
```

And I'd like to get only the line in each subgroup delimited by 'A Column' where I have the highest value in 'C Column'. Eg.: I'll get:

```
A Column | B Column | C Column 
------------------------------
11       | Text3    | 30
12       | Text4    | 20
13       | Text33   | 09
```

Could someone help me? I'm still learning about sql.

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Yes.. This is the primary question :)

Comment: Sorry... I'm using MS Access 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you didn't specified the RDBMS system so I want to provide a query which works for almost all of RDBMSs which supports SQL (use a `self join` with `group by` like below):

```
select tb2.id,tb1.b,tb1.c from 
(select t1.b,max(t1.c) c from table_name t1 group by tb1.b) tb1
join table_name tb2 on tb1.b=tb2.b and tb1.c=tb2.c
```

Comment: In your query you used two tables, but I'm working with just one. Why do you use two?

Comment: the query uses only one table, review it again

Comment: Hmmm. Had neglected to modify my answer for all databases. Just came across with my answered questions. @Farhęg +1 for correct answer :)

Comment: @Avidan, thank you bro, your answer is also perfect for each RDBMS which supports row_number and cte, just accept my apologize if I not upvote it because upvoting each other is not valid in SO.

Comment: @Farhęg  Hmmm. Bro. Right is right. Answers are upvoted only when those are perfectly right.according to question. I never mind :)
...And am much junior to you.... Here just to learn and explore few things/ Technologies. :)

Comment: @Avidan, please don't say that, you are not junior to me because there is too much things that you know but I don't know specially in IT(RDBMS/Programming,Etc), anyway. good luck and all the bests for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below in t-sql, MS SQL Server:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A_Column ORDER BY C_Column DESC) AS rn
   FROM table_name
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Please find similar example here:
[Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)